# Cannot deploy javax mvc application on Glassfish 5 server using Java EE 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee-8, glassfish-5

I have got problem with deploying my web project into Glassfish 5 server using javax.mvc-api. I am doing everything similar like in book but this doesn't work.

I am using Glassfish 5 server as provider for my Java EE 8 project.

My pom.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.zerg.web</groupId>
<artifactId>PlanYourTime</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mvc/javax.mvc-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mvc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mvc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-pr</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.omnifaces/omnifaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My User class

```
package model;

public class User {
private String name;
private String email;

public User(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

}
```

My USerBean class

```
package model;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class UserBean {
    public User getUser(){
        return new User("Elder", "elder@eldermoraes.com");
    }
}
```

My JaxRSConfiguration class

```
package configuration;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

/*
Configures JAX-RS endpoints
 */
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {
}
```

MY user.jsp view

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=UTF-8">
<title>User MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${user.name}/${user.email}</h1>
</body>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And my UserController class where I have got error:

```
package model;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.mvc.Models;
import javax.mvc.annotation.Controller;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Controller
@Path("userController")
public class UserController {
@Inject
Models models;

@Inject
UserBean userBean;

@GET
public String user() {
    models.put("user", userBean.getUser());
    return "/user.jsp";
}
}
```

Intellij idea show me here warning on @Inject Model models
Injection Points Ambiguous Dependencies. Unsatisfied dependency: no bean matches the injection point.

And when I am trying to deploy this I am getting error in Glassfish server.logs

```
[2019-03-17T20:19:29.721+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] 
[javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin- 
listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1552850369721] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: 
Unsatisfied dependencies for type Models with qualifiers @Named
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Named 
model.UserController.models
at model.UserController.models(UserController.java:0)

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied 
dependencies for type Models with qualifiers @Named
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Named 
model.UserController.models
at model.UserController.models(UserController.java:0)

at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:375)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:287)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:140)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:161)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:504)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:479)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:481)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:230)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

I am doing everything similar like in book step by step and using same Glassfish 5 server as them and this doesn't work. I was also searching how to solve this problem but nothing helped me. I would be very thankful for every help.